# Loop to add columns based on rank so there is only a single row for each table 1 entry

Tags: sql-server

I am still new to writing Microsoft Server SQL and have a query I need to write that has to loop to have the result on a single row for each record that will have columns based on increasing rank value in a table.

I had been creating temp table but the rank can increase up to 75 and writing 75-80 temp tables seems repetitive.  Is there a way to write loop that will have a single row for each table 1 entry that will pull columns for each table 3 event that has increasing rank?

I am sure this is as clear as mud but I would be ope to any suggestions.  Here is the temp table example of what I had used before for a similar yet smaller request. Below is kind of what I am looking to do.take multiple rows of the same account and transpose the codes into columns so there is only one row per account.

```
Account Code    Rank        
1234    d123    1       
1234    g1234   2       
1234    h123    3       
1234    m123    4       

Account Code    Code    Code    Code
1234    d123    g1234   h123    m123
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do here but I suspect looping is the root of the problem. We should avoid loops whenever possible. We can help but need some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: can you explain what your source data looks like, what you need to do (not how you think you need to do it,) and what you want your results to look like?

Comment: I have multiple tables that I need to reference.  I have an account that is the primary key between the table.  The account can have many rows of the "Code" that I need to pull.  Those codes need to be compiled into a single row for each account number.  The number of potential codes can vary each month. Codes are ranked so I need to pull based on that rank.

Comment: AccountNumber,Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4,Code5,Code6,Code7